# i18next translation is not rendered in EJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, i18next

I have included i18next in my Express application and configured it as follows:

```js
const i18next = require('i18next');
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend');
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

i18next
    .use(Backend)
    .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        preload: ['en', 'de']
    });
```

The paths for my translation files are correct, and look like this:

locales/de/translation.json

```json
{
  "SignIn": "Anmelden",
  "Username": "Benutzername",
  "Password": "Passwort",
  "Login": "Anmelden"
}
```

locales/en/translation.json

```json
{
  "SignIn": "Sign in",
  "Username": "Username",
  "Password": "Password",
  "Login": "Login"
}
```

When rendering the ejs template, I pass the t function of i18next to the view like this

```ts
res.render("index",{t:i18next.t});
```

In the template, I then use the value as follows:

```ejs
<h2 class="ui center aligned header"><%= t("SignIn") %></h2>
```

The result is that nothing is displayed at all, neither the fallback language nor German, since my browser is German and the Language Detector should detect that.

I read that you have to rebind the t functions to make it work in the view, I tried that as well, like this:

```ts
res.render("index", {t: i18next.t.bind(i18next.t)});
```

As soon as I do that, the fallback language is rendered, if I change it to German, German is rendered as well.

But the language is not detected automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `t` function is already available for the templates via `http-middleware`, without explicitly passing an object from the backend.

So far, it seems everything work fine.